# EBS volume stuck at file write

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a golang binary which emits logs to a file. This file is located in AWS EBS volume. The binary runs 24/7, But today I found that OS is restarting the process sometimes and reason in dmseg is it has been stuck in acquiring a write lock. I checked disk space, it looks fine. 
Can someone help me in what direction I should proceed?

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Please edit your question to show, at minimum, the **exact** error from the syslog/dmesg. Also mention the type (gp2, io1, sc1, st1, etc.) and size of the EBS volume, and whether you maintain EBS snapshots of the volume. If you don't maintain snapshots of the volume, consider making a snapshot (in the EC2 console) to verify that it succeeds.